# How can I DataBind a textbox from the parent window with values from the child with MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I just took over a project from another programmer who is no longer here. It was created using the MVVM Pattern (using the MVVM Light toolkit). I am new to MVVM and have been trying to learn the basics fast. Currently I am having trouble getting a selected value from a Child Window back to the Parent Window.

From another post on SO I learned that I should use the same ViewModel for both the parent and the child so I think I have the basics right. However I have not been able to get the selected values back to the parent. Below is a sample set of code similar to the production code.

My ViewModel for both pages is here

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Vendor selectedVendor = null;
    List<Vendor> vendors;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        OpenVendorWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(VendorSelect);
        VendorSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(VendorSelected);
        LoadVendors();
    }

    public ICommand OpenVendorWindowCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand VendorSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

    void VendorSelect()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("SelectVendor"));
    }

    public Vendor SelectedVendor
    {
        get { return selectedVendor; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedVendor != value)
            {
                selectedVendor = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    void VendorSelected()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SelectedVendor.VendorName);
    }

    public List<Vendor> Vendors
    {
        get
        {
            return vendors;
        }
        set
        {
            if (vendors != value)
            {
                vendors = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadVendors()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = Vendor.GetVendors();
        Vendors = new List<Vendor>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Vendors.Add(new Vendor()
            {
                VendorID = Convert.ToInt32(row["VendorID"]),
                VendorCode = Convert.ToString(row["VendorCode"]),
                VendorName = Convert.ToString(row["VendorName"])
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am at the point that the Child Window opens and I am able to select a vendor from a ListBox. After the selection I press a button (VendorSelectedCommand) and it is at that point I want the textbox on the Parent Window to be filled with the SelectedVendor.VendorName value.

This is the XAML from my Child Window

```
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox
            Height="200"
            Margin="5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="GhostWhite"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Vendors}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedVendor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3">
                        <StackPanel Margin="15">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="175" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                    Foreground="Black"
                                    Text="{Binding VendorName}" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                    Foreground="Black">
                                    <Run Text=" (" />
                                    <Run Text="{Binding VendorCode}" />
                                    <Run Text=") " />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Button Command="{Binding VendorSelectedCommand}" Content="Send Vendor Back" />
    </StackPanel>
```

And lastly this is the XAML for the Parent Window with what I think is the correct binding

```
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Margin="10" Text="{Binding SelectedVendor.VendorName}" />
        <Button
            Margin="10"
            Command="{Binding OpenVendorWindowCommand}"
            Content="Select Vendor" />
    </StackPanel>
```

I have tried every possible combination of Binding Syntax that I can think of and have tried multiple different ways in the code behind to catch and bind it but have not been able to get it right. What is missing from my ViewModel to make this work?

**Edit** For clarity (and in response to a comment) I am adding the DataContext, which I had in the Constructor of the Views.

```
public partial class VendorView : Window
{
    private MainViewModel _vm = null;
    public VendorView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _vm = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = _vm;
    }
}
```

**Edit #2** I am opening the second page with this. This is very simple sample app with only two pages so I didn't want to get bogged down with navigation until I have a better handle on Binding.

```
    private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
    {
        if (msg.Notification == "SelectVendor")
        {
            var vendorView = new VendorView();
            vendorView.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Having the parent and the child to use the Same ViewModel is (by me at least) not the correct way. The ViewModel is an abstraction of the View. Meaning that the content of the parent should be reflected in the ViewModel. So if your Parent Window holds a child/several children-windows then the ViewModel should have some reference to it/them. Like a `UserControl` that contains the children you want to display.

Comment: Also I can't see anywhere in your code where you declare the `DataContext` for the View.

Comment: This is where I read about using the same ViewModel for both Views but I wasn't able to translate this into a solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507527/passing-value-from-child-window-to-parent-window-using-wpf-and-mvvm-pattern

Comment: Where and how are you opening the child window and how do you set the DataContext of the windows?

Comment: The first edit shows how I am setting the DataContext. The second edit shows how I am opening the second page.